# python and opencv 2 imwrite

Tags: python, opencv, io

I have been trying to learn to use the opencv library for python using this "tutorial":

https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#filtering

In other tutorials I could get it working fine, but here with smoothing/blurring the images I couldn't find a way to *"print"* the output.

By *print* I mean saving the modified file (with another name as the code suggests) in the disk.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cv2          
#import sys          # sys.exit() [used for argparse exit]
import numpy as np  
#import argparse     # not used here, because it's not really the problem
#import os           # to validate the image path with argparse


def hist_eq(imagem, name):
    cv2.imwrite("hist_eq" + name, cv2.equalizeHist(imagem))


def media(imagem, name, tam):
    mascara = np.ones((tam, tam), np.float32) / (tam ^ 2)
    img = cv2.filter2D(imagem, -1, mascara)
    cv2.imwrite("filtro_media_" + name, img)


def mediana(imagem, name, tam):
    imagem = cv2.medianBlur(imagem, tam)
    cv2.imwrite("filtro_mediana_" + name, imagem)


def gaussiano(imagem, name, tam):
    teste = cv2.GaussianBlur(imagem, (tam, tam), 0)
    cv2.imwrite("filtro_gaussiano_" + name, teste)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nome = str(sys.argv[1])
    imagem = cv2.imread(nome)
    gs_imagem = cv2.cvtColor(imagem, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gaussiano(gs_imagem, nome, 11)
    media(gs_imagem, nome, 11)
    mediana(gs_imagem, nome, 11)
    hist_eq(gs_imagem, nome)
```

Comment: PS: what bugs me most is the lack of any error message, I mean imwrite could at least print an error and tell why it isn't working.

Comment: Do you pass also extension in name variable?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Did you check whether or not `imagem` actually has anything in it? Try printing `imagem` and `gs_imagem` after imread. Opencv is notorious for not notifying a 'null' image.

Comment: I wasn't getting any error, but when I tried cv2.imwrite after the imread (as suggested by @slider) I got this error:

OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (could not find a writer for the specified extension) in imwrite_, file /home/rodrigo/Desktop/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.5/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp, line 275
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pratica_2.py", line 89, in <module>
    cv2.imwrite("teste", imagem)
cv2.error: /home/rodrigo/Desktop/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.5/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:275: error: (-2) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function imwrite_

Comment: I've made a similar program (that works) and looks very like it :
http://pastebin.com/gDYUUUmZ (first steps with opencv) 

http://pastebin.com/x10QfqCP (the full program of this question) 

if you look at both you'll see that the imread and imwrite are actually the same on both, but only works on the first one.

Comment: As @slider said, try just `print imagem` and `print gs_imagem` after you `imread` them.

Comment: @cm2, that is exactly what I've tried when I got the error posted on two comments above.

Comment: Your comment above says you used `cv2.imwrite` not `print`.  The point @slider was making was that when you issue `cv2.imread`, the returned value might not actually be what you think it was, if there was a problem reading the data.  If you just `print imagem`, it should tell you if it is a valid image object.

Comment: The output from print are matrix like objects: [[5 5 5 ..., 5 5 5]
 [5 5 5 ..., 5 5 5]
 [5 5 5 ..., 5 5 5]
 ..., 
 [5 5 5 ..., 5 5 5]
 [5 5 5 ..., 5 5 5]
 [5 5 5 ..., 5 5 5]]

my apologies for misunderstanding what you both said.